# how do i make labels list manually for my imported images in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
fq=glob.glob("*.jpg") # ['0.jpg','1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg'],labels for images=[1,1,1,0,0]
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=onehot))
```

assuming that there is  just  **2 classes** and **batch size is 2** and **logits are [2,2] tensor**,how do i make `"onehot"` variable list which contains one hot encoded labels like **[1,0]** for image 0,1,2  .jpg and **[0,1]** for image 3,4 .jpg. much thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you want `labels = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`, just use

```py
tf.one_hot(labels, depth=2)
```

Results in a tensor of one-hot labels:

```py
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Note [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) puts the `1` in whatever index is indicated by the first input you give it. Also note that this is a tensor, so if you run this in a notebook and then try to print the tensor, you will get something like:

```py
<tf.Tensor 'one_hot:0' shape=(5, 2) dtype=float32>
```

It's not until it is evaluated that it takes on the values shown above, but that's just how TensorFlow do.

So if you have a batch size of two, you are feeding two labels per training step to your network and then converting those labels (either in the training step or in your network) to one-hot. I would do something like:

```py
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])  # 'None' means it has one dimension that is determined by your batch size
# ... define your network ...
loss_op = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                                  labels=tf.one_hot(labels))
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(loss_op)
```

Then in your training process:

```py
for _ in range(num_iter):
    d = # generate data batch
    t = # generate label batch, e.g. [1, 1] for the first two images
    _, batch_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss_op],
                             feed_dict={data: d, labels: t})
```

Comment: thanks for your response,i've already tried but as i said logits variable shape is [2,2] your solution is going to make   *onehot* shape of [5,2]. It is throwing an error  **ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 5 for 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [2,2], [5,2].**  am i missing something?

Comment: No way, just feed whatever the labels are for your particular batch to your network. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @yinyang I updated to show how to use this in the way that I think you want. I did not run this, so it is possible you will get a dimension error from how the placeholder is defined. If so, try `tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your input array is a NumPy array, you can use `np.eye`:

```
label_array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
onehot_array = np.eye(2)[label_array]
```

The result is: [[ 0.  1.], [ 0.  1.], [ 0.  1.], [ 1.  0.], [ 1.  0.]]